# Remove line gapping in PDF

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have used following code given below to print a line of text in pdf using itextsharp library. But line gap is more as shown in image here

[image: here is image]

```
PdfContentByte cb1 = writer.DirectContent;
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb1);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(
    new Phrase(new Chunk(text, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 09, Font.BOLD))),
    46, 270, 550, 36, 25, Element.ALIGN_LEFT | Element.ALIGN_TOP);
ct.Go();
```

Answer (score 1):

This large gap is exactly what you ask for!

Consider

```
ct.SetSimpleColumn(
    new Phrase(new Chunk(text, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 09, Font.BOLD))),
    46, 270, 550, 36, 25, Element.ALIGN_LEFT | Element.ALIGN_TOP);
```

The parameters of `SetSimpleColumn` are specified as

```
/**
 * Simplified method for rectangular columns.
 * @param phrase a <CODE>Phrase</CODE>
 * @param llx the lower left x corner
 * @param lly the lower left y corner
 * @param urx the upper right x corner
 * @param ury the upper right y corner
 * @param leading the leading
 * @param alignment the column alignment
 */
virtual public void SetSimpleColumn(Phrase phrase, float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury, float leading, int alignment)
```

**Leading** in PDFs is defined as

> #### 9.3.5 Leading
>
> The leading parameter, *T*<sub>l</sub>, shall be specified in unscaled text space units. It specifies the vertical distance between the baselines of adjacent lines of text, as shown in Figure 44.
>
> [image: Leading]
>
> *(ISO 32000-1)*

In your case you have 9-point text with a 25-point leading and, therefore, huge gaps. If you want smaller gaps, choose a smaller leading here.